# Error attempting to write html tagged text to .txt file

Tags: python

Receiving the following error attempting to write dictionary key value containing HTML tags to a text file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jackboland/PycharmProjects/NLTK_example/JsonToTxt.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 10: invalid start byte
```

I have a set of JSON files.  I am successfully extracting that data to a Python dictionary.  Then, from there, I am identifying the dictionary key whose value is the longest and extracting that value to a text file.  The code works for all JSON files whose longest dictionary key value is a string.  It is throwing the above error for files whose longest dictionary key value is html content.

```
with open(path + file) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for value in data.values():  # gets the value of each dictionary key
    value = str(value)  # converts the value of each dictionary key to a string enabling counting total characters
    vLength = len(value)  # calculates the length of each value in every dictionary key to enable identifying only the longest of the key values
    if vLength > 100:  # if the length of a value is over 200 characters, it prints that, this insures capturing the opinion text no matter what dictionary key it is in
    f = open(newpath + file[:-5] + ".txt", 'w+')
    f.write(value)
    f.close()
```

The dictionary key values that are strings are parsing from the dictionary and into a text file.  It is only the dictionary key values that contain html that are not being written to a text file.

Comment: What language is your JSON in? It looks like you have a character that isn't UTF-8. You could try encoding and then decoding in the same line.

Comment: Being relatively new to JSON, I cannot tell you what language the JSON is in.  I only see that values in dictionary keys that do not have html are exporting to my text file without incident and values containing html tags result in empty text files.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the json you are attempting to read/write?

Comment: JSON dictionary key value example with HTML tags that is causing error.  {
  "html_columbia": "<p><center>                                 OPINION</center>\n<strong>{&#182; 1}</strong> Appellant Stanley E. Hoff appeals his conviction for violation of a civil protection order in the Municipal Court of Fairfield County. The relevant facts leading to this appeal are as follows.</p>\n<p>  <strong>{&#182; 2}</strong> </p>",
  "extracted_by_ocr": false,
  "opinions_cited": [
    "https://www.courtlistener.com:80/api/rest/v3/opinions/3712642/"

Answer (score 0):

Python tries to convert a byte-array to a unicode string. When it tries this, it encounters a byte sequence which is not allowed in utf-8-encoded strings (here at 0xc0 in position 10).

Try reading the file in a binary format so that the content of the file remain as bytes.

```
with open(path + file, 'rb') as json_data:
     //rest of the code
```

If this doesn't work, manually specify encoding formats.

Example :

```
open(path + file, encoding="utf-8") as json_data
     //rest of the code
```

You can get the various encoding formats here.

https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, both options resulted in the same error unfortunately.

Comment: encoding="utf-8" was for example only. Try using different encoding formats given in the link appropriate to your file format.

https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html